# Ruby on Rails ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime-error

I am trying to create line_items but I am getting this error

app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:52:in `create'

which references to this line

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product

@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product => product)
```

the full code is below

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :description, :image_url, :price, :title

   default_scope :order => 'title'

   has_many :line_items
   before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
   #more code here...
   private

   # ensure that there are no line items referencing this product
   def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
     if line_items.empty?
       return true
     else
       errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
       return false
      end
   end

end



def create
   @cart = current_cart
   product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
   #the error is HERE!!
   @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product => product)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `attr_accessible :product` in your LineItem class.

This is a security that forces you to whitelist which fields can be mass assigned in order to avoid hacks like github had ;)

Comment: Mhh what if you use :product instead ?

Comment: try  attr_accessible :description, :image_url, :price, :title, :product_id OR  attr_accessible :description, :image_url, :price, :title, :product, one of them should work, but i don't remember which one you have to use.

Comment: i discovered the problem.. had to put attr_acessible :product inside LineItem model

Comment: Indeed, did not see the association, will edit my answer, can you accept ?